# Strange problems with Eclipse after I upgraded my OS to Yosemite

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

My eclipse was working fine until few days back i upgraded my OS from Mavericks to Yosemite.
Every time i clean the project, Eclipse seems to add new id in R.java  file like `public static final int someting on list=0x7f050057;` , at the beginning i went through entire resource files to check if i have done some mistakes to which i couldn't find one, but later when i removed that line from R.java file, saved it and restarted Eclipse the error seem to have gone and  I was able to run the app on my phone. This error is occuring every time i clean the project.

I have also tried importing this project to Eclipse on Mavericks OS, but on this case the problem never occured. Is this something do with Eclipse and OS or I have done something wrong?.

If anyone have gone through this kinda of problem and solved it, please help me solve it too. This problem bugs me and everytime i need to restart Eclipse.

Comment: When you update you os check the version of java the default changes !

Comment: I manually installed jdk version 8

Comment: when you do java -version in the terminal what do you get ?

Comment: i get java version "1.8.0_25"

Comment: can you share you pom.

Comment: You mean the entire code?